# Pandas - querying / filtering a period[Q-MAR] dtype column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a period[Q-MAR] column, and I would like to filter the data from the latest fiscal year. Is there any methods in `pandas` to filter / query a period[Q-MAR] dtype column. The following is the code to create the required dataframe:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([datetime.date(2019, 10, 25), datetime.date(2019, 6, 25),
                   datetime.date(2020, 3, 25), datetime.date(2018, 10, 25),
                   datetime.date(2017, 10, 25), datetime.date(2018, 6, 25),
                   datetime.date(2017, 10, 25), datetime.date(2019, 7, 25)],
                  columns=['dates'])
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
df['quater_info'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['dates'], freq='Q-MAR')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    dates       quater_info
0   2019-10-25  2020Q3
1   2019-06-25  2020Q1
2   2020-03-25  2020Q4
3   2018-10-25  2019Q3
4   2017-10-25  2018Q3
5   2018-06-25  2019Q1
6   2017-10-25  2018Q3
7   2019-07-25  2020Q2
```

The following is the code I wrote to get the data from the latest fiscal year:

```
print(df[df['quater_info'].astype(str).str.contains(str(df['quater_info'].max().year))])
```

Output:

```
    dates       quater_info
0   2019-10-25  2020Q3
1   2019-06-25  2020Q1
2   2020-03-25  2020Q4
7   2019-07-25  2020Q2
```

Is there any better way to query the `period[Q-MAR]` dtype column in pandas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you need to convert to string:

```
max_year = df.quater_info.dt.qyear.max()
df[df.quater_info.dt.qyear.eq(max_year)]
```

Output:

```
       dates quater_info
0 2019-10-25      2020Q3
1 2019-06-25      2020Q1
2 2020-03-25      2020Q4
7 2019-07-25      2020Q2
```

Other than that, I don't think there is a faster/shorter way.

Comment: Thank you, it is faster. I didnt know that we can chain `dt` to the period column. Thanks.